# SHA-256 NodeJS vs .NET C#

Tags: c#, node.js

I'm using SHA-256 with Hex to hash some text. However I am finding that the hashed text in my Node implementation differs from my .NET C# implementation.

In NodeJS I have the following:

```
return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(text).digest('hex');
```

and in .NET C# I have:

```
private static string Hash(string text)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

    using (var generator = new SHA256Managed())
    {
        byte[] hash = generator.ComputeHash(bytes);
        return BytesToHex(hash);
    }
}

private static string BytesToHex(byte[] bytes)
{
    var hex = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in bytes)
    {
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
    }

    return hex.ToString();
}

return Hash(text);
```

What have I done wrong in the NodeJS version?

As this means when I try and use my NodeJS app with hashes created by my .NET app the hashes don't match up!

**Update: Apparently this could be due to charset...**

So I tried:

```
return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(text, 'utf8').digest('hex');
```

But the hash is the same as before? So using utf8 instead of binary hasn't actually made any difference to the returned hash... And it's still mismatched from the .NET version.

Comment: Post an executable repro including some text.

Comment: FWIW [update](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_update_data_input_encoding) / [digest](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_digest_encoding) are legacy methods, you should just directly write your text to the stream ([Hash](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hash) will internally perform the digest).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is a mismatch in encoding used in both systems, [Encoding.Unicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will use `UTF-16` format, not `UTF-8` - the update you made on the NodeJS side is still required as omitting the `input_encoding` parameter means it will default to `binary`. However, you also need to update the .NET side to use `UTF-8` encoding

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
```

---

Alternatively, you can update the Node side to use UTF-16 using the, undocumented, `ucs2` encoding

```
crypto.createHash('sha256').update(text, 'ucs2')
```

*© IronGeek*

Comment: Is it possible to use UTF-16 with NodeJS?

Comment: @Cameron according to the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_update_data_input_encoding) the only supported encoding types are `utf8`, `ascii` or `binary`.

Comment: Okay thanks. That's a bit annoying as we have a DB full of hashes coded in UTF-16 haha but I guess we'll have to switch them to get this working for Node as well. Thanks again.

Comment: @Cameron that's only the `Crypto` lib shipped with Node....I'd have a gander over on NPM you might find there is a lib that does support UTF-16.

Comment: @Cameron try using `crypto.createHash('sha256').update(text, 'ucs2')` to match the .NET Unicode encoding

Comment: @IronGeek oh cool, looks like the docs could be doing with an update!